# NSURLConnection throws after updating to Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, try-catch, nsurlconnection

Before the Swift 2.0 Update this code worked perfectly to download my JSON File from the Server with a PHP Script:

```
let url = NSURL(string: webAdress)
let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)
```

After the Update Xcode asked me to do some changes. I did and the code had no Error, but it always throws...

```
    let url = NSURL(string: webAdress)
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var reply = NSData()
    do {
    reply = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR")
    }
```

Looking forward to your solutions!

Comment: Print out the error?? you can get it right inside the catch.

Comment: print(error) will do this - no need to declare an error variable (just clarifying for you Rob). See my answer for the Swifty way!

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using the new NSURLSession - apparently NSURLConnection has been deprecated in iOS 9.

```
let url = NSURL(string: webAddress)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    print(data)
    print(response)
    print(error)
})?.resume()
```

I think it's super clean, there's just not much documentation on it. Let me know if you have any trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is my output of your code:
`nil
nil
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "URL nicht unterstützt" UserInfo=0x1567d8b00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1567a8c00 "Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork-Fehler -1002.)", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=www.`_(...)_`.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=www.`_(...)_`.php, NSLocalizedDescription=URL nicht unterstützt})`

Comment: Do you know what this could be?

Comment: Data and response are nil because you had an error. The error is defined there as optional (just like data and response) so you'll have to unwrap it if you want to use any of that info. You're getting error 1002 which corresponds to NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL and is usually cause by a missing http://. However that's not the case here - I'll look into the error.

Comment: Replace "http://droplync.com" with "http://google.com" and it works fine (there's some issue with SSL on my server I'm in the middle of fixing). If you provide me with the URL you're hitting I can try to get it working with that.

Comment: Hmm, that gives error 1004 (Could not connect to server) yet I can hit it manually... I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: That's what I found out so far, too. If you find anything, it would be a delight! Tanks a lot!!!

Comment: Alright, I've spent way too much time on this. I'm certain the issue is with your server - check your logs.

Comment: Strange! The server works perfectly on android...Nevertheless thanks a lot! I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maximilian hi,
I have the same unsolved issue, the proposed solution by Sidetalker using NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest is not what you looking for since the NSURLSession API is highly asynchronous (according with Apple documentation) and the code you had implemented in swift 1.2 was synchronous.
in the other hand, NSURLConnection has been deprecated in iOS 9 therefore the code you wrote is probably not building, right?

my suggested solution is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: webAdress)
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
var responseCode = -1
let group = dispatch_group_create()
dispatch_group_enter(group)
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(_, response, _) in
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
}
dispatch_group_leave(group)
})!.resume()
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
//rest of your code...
```

please let me know if its now OK