# Getting Twitter profile image with Parse in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform

I am trying to get Twitter Profile picture using swift 2.

This link gives a description of how it is done for swift:
[Getting Twitter profile image with Parse in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924749/getting-twitter-profile-image-with-parse-in-swift)

but the thing  is `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated and replace by NSURLSession. The `PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.signRequest` requires a `NSMutableURLRequest` but from the method mentioned to replace sync request I am getting a `NSURLRequest`. How do I make the code work?

I tried to write this code to make it work but am stumped:

```
     if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {

        let screenName = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName!


        let requestString = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + screenName!)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestString!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)


        PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.signRequest(request)

        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error: NSError?



        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            print(data)
            print(response)
            print(error)
        }).resume()



        if error == nil {

            let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error)


            let names: String! = result?.objectForKey("name") as! String

            let separatedNames: [String] = names.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

            //self.firstName = separatedNames.first!
            //self.lastName = separatedNames.last!


            let urlString = result?.objectForKey("profile_image_url_https") as! String

            let hiResUrlString = urlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_normal", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)


            let twitterPhotoUrl = NSURL(string: hiResUrlString)
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: twitterPhotoUrl!)
            let twitterImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data:imageData!)
        }
```

[NSURLConnection throws after updating to Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830902/nsurlconnection-throws-after-updating-to-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, I was able to get the Twitter image to be retrieved using:

```
if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {

    let screenName = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.screenName!
    let requestString = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + screenName!)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestString!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
    PFTwitterUtils.twitter()?.signRequest(request)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)

        if error == nil {
            var result: AnyObject?
            do {
                result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            } catch let error2 as NSError? {
                print("error 2 \(error2)")
            }

            let names: String! = result?.objectForKey("name") as! String
            let separatedNames: [String] = names.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

            //self.firstName = separatedNames.first!
            //self.lastName = separatedNames.last!

            let urlString = result?.objectForKey("profile_image_url_https") as! String
            let hiResUrlString = urlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_normal", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
            let twitterPhotoUrl = NSURL(string: hiResUrlString)
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: twitterPhotoUrl!)
            let twitterImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data:imageData!)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

I rolled the result handling into the data task and fixed the `JSONObjectWithData:options:` call for Swift 2.